# Find zeroes in complex plane for $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find the zeros and order of $F(z)=(z+2-i)^2 $ where $z$ is in complex plane

What i did until now:
expanded and ordered by $f(z)=\text{Re}(z)+ i\text{Im}(z)$.

Both $\text{Re}(z)=0$ and $\text{Im}(z)=0$, so because $f(z)= (z^2+4z+3)-i(4+2z)=0$ I try to set both parts to $0$. But I am not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want...is it to solve the equation $$(z+2-i)^2=0\;\;,\;\;z\in\Bbb C\;?$$

Comment: Zeroes is when F(z) = 0 and the order when derivative of f(z) is different to zero.

in complex numbers if  z= 0 means that Real part =0 and Imaginary part is equal to zero, too. So I am not sure about your answer because you are not considering that. Thank you.

Comment: Try to focus on what I ask you, @user101052: what is **your** question? Believe me, I and most other answerers here handle pretty well complex analysis. Your mixing $\;F(z)\;$ and the derivative of $\;f(z)\;$ is completely unclear.

Comment: @DonAntonio The OP is trying to find and classify the zeroes of $F(z)=(z+2-i)^2$.  Solving the equation $(z+2-i)^2=0$ is only half the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your technique will work but it is somewhat painful. In the real numbers, do you know something about the zeros of an equation $F(x) = (x-\alpha)^2$ and their order? Your problem is the same, but in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: That is what i tried to do. I expand the cuadratic binomial and the ordered by real and imaginary parts. then I equate and found the roots. 1 root for Imaginary(z=-2) and 2 zeros for real part (z=-3 and z=-1). That is what I think but i am not sure. I think is not possible to equate z+2-i =0 only. But I appreciate your collaboration.

Comment: @user101052: It is in fact possible to set $z+2-i=0$. This is because $F(x)=(z+2-i)(z+2-i)=0$, so at least one factor must be zero. But both factors are $z+2-i$, so this must be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your method doesn't make sense. $z$ is a complex number so it is of the form $z=x+iy$ for some $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $f(z)=(z^2+4z+3)-i(4+2z)$ is only in the form $\text{Re }z+\text{Im }z$ if $z$ is real. I think what you mean was to let $z=x+iy$ and then you are trying to find the zeros of $F(z)=f(x,y)=\big((x+iy)+2-i\big)^2$. While this will work, it's computationally expensive.

Instead, just remember that as with real numbers, $z^2=0$ if and only if $z=0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Since $(z+2-i)$ is just some complex number, its square can only be zero if it is 0. Then we have $z+2-i=0$ which implies $z=-2+i$. As in the comments, one could notice that it is of order 2 immediately because $(z+2-i)^2=(z+2-i)(z+2-i)$. In general, you check to see how many of the derivatives also have this complex number as a zero. Using the derivative rules, $F'(z)=2(z+2-i)$. Notice then that $F'(-2+i)=0$. So $z=-2+i$ is a zero of at least order 2. Now  because $F''(z)=2$, we know that the only zero of $F(z)$ is $z=-2+i$ and it is of order 2.

Comment: Thank You. Excellent explanation.